# Scan multiple pages into single file automatically

Tags: windows-xp, scanner, hp-laserjet

I have a HP Laserjet M2727mf printer/scanner.  The Windows scanner wizard will allow us to select "document feeder" as the paper source, so that we can scan multiple pages at once.  However, each page is saved as an individual image file.

Is there a way that all the pages could be combined automatically, into 1 file?

I realise it can be done manually, but an office needs to scan an entire filing cabinet.

Comment: Not to patronize you, but have you tried all the options to ensure it won't scan into a single document? Obviously JPGs will be separate, but often there's such and option for PDFs and TIFFs.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got the files of the scans on disk you could use a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to combine all the images into a big image, PDF, or multipage TIFF.

eg:

> $ convert 1329.jpg 1330.jpg -adjoin identity.tiff

ImageMagick can also connect directly to [XSane](http://www.xsane.org/xsane-win32.html) I think on Windows in order to access the scanner. I've never tried this though.

Comment: can the ImageMagick be scripted, and to run on many folders?

Comment: This is not a simple program to install, or even use, perhaps.  It has to be easy for non-technical users to use.

Comment: Yes ImageMagick can be scripted via COM (vbscript, jscript etc) or called directly in batch files. Installing is as simple as downloading the Windows installer and running it.